# android - How to build a new app inside the app

Tags: android

I've an application , I need to build a new app from the same app but with only a small different in asset folder .

I mean it makes a copy from it self but change a value inside the asset folder.

is it possible? 
How can I do so ?

Comment: This sounds like something you should do something like this at the building layer. This way you can change the files included in a particular build. First figure out how your code is built and then figure out a way to bring in alternative build variants which have differences.

Comment: Or can you provide more information about what you mean? Like you want a distinctly different app that is the exact same except for the contents of the assets folder? In that case you likely are best changing the application id and and relevant namespace info in each file... Otherwise, @JoxTraex is right, you should change the asset in your asset folder and rebuild.

Comment: Use `Flavors` in building such apps, that will be the same codebase with different config.